# Проблема с правами папок и файлов после переустановки Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, права, chown

Стоит Nginx+Apache+Php-Fpm на debian 8.
Недавно переустанавливал некоторые пакеты сервера в том числе и apache.
В итоге полетели права на файлы сайта. Скрипты не могут записывать(только с 777), а старые файлы(пр. картинки) нельзя перезаписать. Как я выяснил, проблема оказалась не в правах, а в группе.
До этого было так и все писалось хорошо.

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 userst userst    4427776 июл  3 16:10 upload
```

Я попробовал сменить группу `userst` на `www-data` (`chown userst:www-data upload`), и скрипты начали писать как и раньше.
`vipw` выдает такие данные:

```
...
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
...
userst:x:501:501:db_userst:/var/www/userst/data:/bin/bash
...
```

Можно ли как-то дать `userst` такие же права как у `www-data`?

Я пробовал добавить `userst` в группу `www-data`.

Проверял `/etc/group` вроде есть запись `www-data:x:33:userst`, но скрипты так и не могут писать `failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

На ответ не тянет, но вам просто надо пользователя `www-data` добавить в группу `userst`.

Comment: это не работает. Я пробовал и так и так

Comment: А сам скрипт точно их пол www-data работает?

Comment: я выставлял права как для скрипта который пишет, так и для каталога. При `userst:userst` не пишет, а при `userst:www-data` пишет. Раньше всегда было `userst:userst`. Никогда не изменял.

Comment: В нстройках apache какой юзер и группа определены. И вообще у вас же php-fpm смотрите `pool.d/www` смотрите группу и юзера для пула. Может у вас он раньше работал от `userst:userst` а при установке apache встал какой нибудь другой интерпритатор который работает от www-data...

Comment: стоит `user = www-data
group = www-data`
У меня и nginx работает от `www-data` и всегда работали от `www-data`. Никогда это не менял. Проблема скорее всего в том, что `userst` потерял свои права.